# PHP How to get the library to which a function belongs?

Tags: php, standard-library

I am working on a personal website written, on server side, in PHP and I don't use any framework. It's purely for pedagogical purpose.

In order to stick with my assignment, I want to use only the standard library.

Do you know a way for me to get the library of a specific function or method ? It could be a php command line tool or whatever.

Thanks !